# Как вывести char* по всю длину игнорируя '\0'?

Tags: c++, строки, char

У меня есть строка, в которой есть куча '\0' символов и мне нужно их учитывать при выводе.

Пример:

```
char *data1 = "a\0bcd\nefg\01234";
std::cout << data1 << std::endl;
```

Вывод будет таким:

```
а
```

Когда ожидается:

```
a bcd
efg 1234
```

Как работать со всей длиной строк вида char*?

Comment: А как вы эту "всю длину" узнаете, если вы не знаете, какой из `\0` последний?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat char* у меня получается из всех символов в string, фактически длина у char* такая же, как у string.

Answer (score 3):

Встречный вопрос - а как вы определите, сколько у вас символов  в строке?

Вот если

```
char data1[] = "a\0bcd\nefg\01234";
```

тогда можно посимвольно (и то, если `data1` не передается куда-то в функцию):

```
for(auto c: data1) cout << c; cout << endl;
```

Если будете передавать в другую функцию - то только вместе с размером. Или через какой-то вектор, строку C++ и т.п.

На всякий случай - учтите, что в вашей конкретной строке как символ будет рассматриваться `\012`, а не просто `\0`.

Comment: У меня к c++ проекту подключен Python.h, где из скрипта я получаю разделенные пробелом числа в одной длинной строке char*, после чего я провожу парсинг с помощью stringstream каждого отдельного числа, переводя его в char и прибавляю этот символ в конец строки string.
Некоторые символы будут '\0', сам string реагирует на них нормально и выводит всю строку, но когда я перевожу его в char* он не выводит дальше первого '\0' символа и strlen() возвращает длину до символа '\0'.
Со string, вместо char* — работу вести не могу, потому что дальше идёт работа с boost::asio, используя char*.

Comment: @5133n, `cо string, вместо char* — работу вести не могу` - а что именно у Вас не получается? Я не вижу проблем (на данный момент) - содержимое строки Вы можете получить через `data()`, размер - `size()`. У Вас могут быть проблемы с выводом данных, но с ASIO - сомневаюсь.

Comment: Работая со `string`, вы знаете, сколько символов в строке, включая нулевые. А с `char*` будут проблемы. Так что лучше, как мне кажется, hаботать все время со `string`. И - у вас числа ограничены 255? что вы их как `char` храните? Вобщем, есть чувство XY-проблемы...

Comment: @Harry, на самом деле тут и правда XY-проблема.
Мне нужно вывести char* для моих unit-тестов, где я использую ещё и вывод.
Если есть возможность сравнить char* во всю длину с другим таким же char*, то это тоже было бы решением моей проблемы.

Comment: Если знаете длину - [`memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) к вашим услугам...